# Java SMS gateway can connect with the comm port but doesn't send message

Tags: java, sms-gateway

This is a program which supposed to send sms to any number but failed. It can connect with the port but doesn't send any message. Anyone helping hand, please?

```
package mateorssms;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;


public class GSMConnect implements SerialPortEventListener, 
CommPortOwnershipListener {

private String comPort = "COM3"; // This COM Port must be connect with GSM Modem or your mobile phone
private String messageString = "hi there!";
private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
private Enumeration portList;
private InputStream inputStream = null;
private OutputStream outputStream = null;
private SerialPort serialPort;

/** Creates a new instance of GSMConnect */
public GSMConnect(String comm) {

    //this.comPort = comm;

}

public boolean init() {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
    portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        if (portId.getName().equals(comPort)) {
        return true;
        }
    }
    }
    return false;
}

public void checkStatus() {
send("AT+CREG?\r\n");
    //reurn outt; 
}

public void dial(String phoneNumber) {
    try {
//dial to this phone number
    messageString = "ATD" + phoneNumber + ";\n\r";
    outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void send(String cmd) {
    try {
        outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
    inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    System.out.println(" Input Stream... " + inputStream.toString());

    } catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    //send("AT+CMGS=\"" + phoneNumber + "\"\r\n");

    send("AT+CMGS=\""+phoneNumber+"\"\r\n");
    send(message + '\032');

}



public void hangup() {
    send("ATH\r\n");
}





public void connect() throws NullPointerException {
    if (portId != null) {
    try {
        portId.addPortOwnershipListener(this);
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MobileGateWay", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        /** These are the events we want to know about*/
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//Register to home network of sim card

    send("ATZ\r\n");

    } else {
    throw new NullPointerException("COM Port not found!!");
    }
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(javax.comm.SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
    switch (serialPortEvent.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2048];
        try {
        while (inputStream.available()>0) 
        {
            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
        }
//print response message
        System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void ownershipChange(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_UNOWNED:
        System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_UNOWNED");
        break;
    case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNED:
        System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_OWNED");
        break;
    case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED:
        System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_INUSED");
        break;
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    GSMConnect gsm = new GSMConnect("COM3");
    if (gsm.init()){
    try {
        gsm.connect();
        gsm.checkStatus();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        gsm.sendMessage("01911507103", "Your Message");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        gsm.hangup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } else {
    System.out.println("Can't init this card");
    }
}
}
```

And here is the output when I run in Netbeans 7.1.

```
run:
COM3: PORT_OWNED
 Input Stream... com.sun.comm.Win32SerialInputStream@a32b
 Input Stream... com.sun.comm.Win32SerialInputStream@a32b
ATZ
OK
Input Stream... com.sun.comm.Win32SerialInputStream@a32b
AT+CMGS="01911507103"
Input Stream... com.sun.comm.Win32SerialInputStream@a32b
ERROR
Input Stream... com.sun.comm.Win32SerialInputStream@a32b
ATH
OK
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the modem in SMS mode with `AT+CMGF=1`

If it still doesn't work, try to send the SMS with `AT+CMGW="<number>"\r\n<message>` which will store the SMS in memory and return an index, e.g. `+CMGW: <index>`. Then issue the command `AT+CMSS=<index>` to actually send it.

Two more things that might help;

- `flush()` your output stream in the send method.
- combine the two `send()` operations inside `sendMessage()` to only one `send()`

Like this:

```
public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    send("AT+CMGS=\""+phoneNumber+"\"\r\n" + message + '\032');
}
```